# swing gui flickering white error

Tags: java, swing, background, opacity, jlabel

I have a Gui I'm making for a program that has an outer container centered to the JFrame that contains an inner container that holds 22*12 cells. When I run this program, the background just flickers white and stays like that. If you could point me out where I'm going wrong that would be awesome!

```
public class Gui extends JFrame
{   
private JPanel outer, inner;
private JLabel[][] labels = new JLabel[22][12];

public Gui()
{
    setBackground(Color.black);
    setSize(1000,1000);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    outer = new JPanel();
    outer.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    outer.setSize(620,920);
    outer.setBackground(Color.white);

    inner = new JPanel();
    inner.setLayout(new GridLayout(22,12,10,10));
    inner.setSize(600,900);
    inner.setBackground(Color.white);

    for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
        {
            labels[i][j] = new JLabel();
            JLabel label = labels[i][j];
            label.setSize(50,50);
            label.setBackground(Color.gray);
            inner.add(label);
        }
    }

    outer.add(inner, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(outer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

The gui is set visible in the main class that instantiates it.

The gui is created and sized correctly. It starts out with a black background then randomly turns to white just after and stays like that.

EDIT: if this is still important:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {

        public void run()
        {
            Gui gui = new Gui();
            gui.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot `setVisible(true)` in your constructor. Try this.

Comment: Post your main() method so we can execute your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the new static variable names which follow final static naming convention. That is the variable should be upper cased:

```
//setBackground(Color.black);
setBackground(Color.BLACK);
```

Don't use setSize() for components. Instead add the components to the frame and then use the pack() method so the components are displayed at their preferred size:

```
//setSize(1000,1000);
add(component1);
add(anotherComponent);
pack();
```

Layout managers use the preferred size not the size as a layout tip:

```
//label.setSize(50,50);
label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
```

This is your main problem. A JLabel is transparent by default, so the background color you set is ignored:

```
label.setBackground(Color.gray);
label.setOpaque(true);
```

By the way, my screen height is only 738, so won't event be able to see you entire frame since you want a height of 22*50. You should be aware of this and probably add your panel to a JScrollPane so people like me can actually use your application. This is why you should not hardcode a preferred size.

Comment: Nice work. Very solid analysis. I much appreciate it! Works great now!